# Html.RadioButtonFor change other radiobutton outside th group

Tags: jquery, razor

I have the following code. No preselected value. My problem is that the first time I click radiobutton LocationID, the radiobutton TypeID has the same value instead of undefined.... Why?? Do you see something wrong???

```
 <div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 radio-reg">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeID, 1, new { onclick = "changeType()" })<span>Type1</span></div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 radio-reg">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeID, 2, new { onclick = "changeType()" })<span>Type2</span></div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 radio-reg">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeID, 3, new { onclick = "changeType()" })<span>Type3</span></div>
</div>  
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 radio-reg">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LocationID, 1, new { onclick = "changeLocation()" })<span>Location1</span></div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 radio-reg">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LocationID, 2, new { onclick = "changeLocation()" })<span>Location2</span></div>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeType() {
var type = $("input[name$='TypeID']:checked").val();          
var location = $("input[name$='LocationID']:checked").val();
console.log( type  + "-" + typeAdLocation);
}

function changeLocation() {
var type=  $("input[name$='TypeID']:checked").val();           
var location = $("input[name$='LocationID']:checked").val();  
console.log(type + "-" + location );
}
```

Comment: Could you set distinct id for all radio buttons

Comment: Same problem with different ids. Added new { id = "typeX", onclick = "changeAdType()" } and  new { id = "locationX", onclick = "changeLocation()" } to the second